# Relative Layout is causing issues with formatting

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, landscape, android-relativelayout

I have been working on an app for my school recently and wanted to clean it up a bit before possibly publishing it. On the scheduling portion of the app, I have 5 buttons that perform actions on a ListView that is also on the screen at the same time. However, I have the issue when I have around 6 or more events on the screen as once the list view takes over the screen and pushes the buttons off the screen, making it so that I cannot delete the events, make new ones, and so on.

I tried setting the list view to a static size (400px) which worked for normal screen orientation, but if the phone is set to landscape view you cannot see the buttons either. With my current code it would appear to work in the XML viewer but in practice is not the case.

This is the code without the static size setting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#551A8B"
    android:textColor="#FFD700"
    >



    <Button android:text="@string/New" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/button3">
    </Button>

    <Button android:text="@string/Edit" 
    android:id="@+id/button4" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button3"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/button3">
    </Button>

    <Button android:text="@string/delete" 
    android:id="@+id/button5" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button4"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/button4">
    </Button>

        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/button7" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/Previousweek"
    android:layout_below="@id/button3">
    </Button>

    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/button6" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/Next"
    android:layout_below = "@id/button3"
    android:layout_toRightOf = "@id/button7">
    </Button>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/listView1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
    android:textColor="#FFD700"
    android:layout_below="@id/button7" 
    android:textSize="10sp" >
    </ListView> 


</RelativeLayout>
```

The XML viewer for this code is:

[image]

Which would lead me to believe it would work fine. I tested it on my emulator and got the following result after entering a bunch of silly events however:

[image]

This result is consistent with multiple versions of the emulator.

How I can fix this problem without using static size constraints that cause landscape orientation issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the buttons into a separate `RelativeLayout` and enclose this and the `ListView` in a vertical `LinearLayout`.

Then:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <RelativeLayout [...]
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!-- Your buttons -->
  </RelativeLayout>
  <ListView android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout
```

The key point here is the height and weight on the `ListView`. This means that it fills the remaining space in the `LinearLayout` after space has been correctly allocated for the buttons.

Comment: This is an approach I took earlier myself but for some reason the buttons still are not even appearing.  I tried clearing the list manually and still the buttons are not appearing.  I'm not sure exactly why this is happening but I assume it must have something to do with my code that uses this xml for formatting.  Any ideas?

Comment: It'd be helpful to see exactly what your XML is like in this state. Could you try and set a fixed height for each of your buttons, perhaps?

Comment: The XML looks like what you posted but instead of the "your buttons" comment it has the code for the buttons as I posted in my original code as well as the xmlns tags required.  I can set a fixed height for the buttons, and in the xml viewer in eclipse the buttons change size and such.  However, in the emulator itself I still cannot see the buttons regardless of size settings.

My idea here is that the buttons are being created but since the listview is not in the relative layout it is simply being placed on top of the buttons instead of below them.  Does that sound like a possibility?

Comment: Not really, the LinearLayout should be make sure that that never happens. If you post your xml, it would be useful to see if there's anything obvious in there I'm missing.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/yFShdL75 is my current XML file that has no different results than I posted in the original question.

http://pastebin.com/bc049gv9 is the code that uses this XML if  you are motivated to look in that to see if there is an issue there.  I understand if you don't wish to do this but here it is if you want to.  Thanks for all of your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution would be to separate the buttons in their own relative layout and put the whole thing in a linear layout, eg:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#551A8B"
    android:textColor="#FFD700">
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#551A8B"
        android:textColor="#FFD700">
        <!-- your buttons -->
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#FFD700"
        android:layout_below="@id/button7"
        android:textSize="10sp">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should never put a ListView in a ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Add a android:weigth in your listView tag and set the android:weigth value to 1. This will work when your list view height and width is set to fill_parent and your list view is covering entire layout. So try it, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use a vertical LinearLayout with two rows of Buttons (each row as a LinearLayout), then give the ListView a layout_weight value of "1". In fact, use layout_weight to clean up the size of your buttons too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button android:text="@string/New" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:id="@+id/button3" />

    <Button android:text="@string/Edit" 
    android:id="@+id/button4" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"  />

    <Button android:text="@string/Delete" 
    android:id="@+id/button5" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"  />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >    

    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/button7" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:text="@string/Previousweek" />

    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/button6" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/Next" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView android:id="@+id/listView1" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_weight="1" 
android:textColor="#FFD700"
android:textSize="10sp" >
</ListView>
```